# Node SerialPort leitura de dados sem quebra de linha

Tags: node.js, quebras-de-linha

estou trabalhando em um projeto com leitura de dados serial, utilizando a biblioteca Node SerialPort, porem ao imprimir os dados no console tenho os dados quebrados em varias linhas, exemplo: send = "1000", obtenho na leitura
received = "1"
"00"
"0"

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
var parser = new Readline({delimiter:'\n\r'});

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const express = require('express');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo.listen(server);


server.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Servidor Online na porta 3000');
});

const port = new SerialPort('COM3', {
 baudRate: 115200,
    dataBits: 8,
    paridade: 'nenhum' ,
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false ,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\n\r')  
});

//define um diretorio commo public para acesso as propriedades
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
 maxAge: '1d'
  }));

// retorna index quano recebe requição
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

 port.open(function()
 {
  console.log('Porta aberta'); 
 });

 port.on('data', function (data)
 {  
   ModbusTCP = data.toString('utf8');
   ModbusTCP = ModbusTCP.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); 
   var infLeng = ModbusTCP.length;  
   
   console.log('tamanho do envio:',infLeng);
   console.log('Valor Hexadeciaml: ' + ModbusTCP);

   // cria conexao de dados entre o js e o index.html
   io.emit('arduino:data', {
    value: data.toString()
   });
 });
```

"0"

Comment: ps dados são enviados a cada 5 segundos pelo arduino.

Comment: tentei definir um delimiter, porem não funcionou !!

Comment: acho que conseguiria resolver se soubesse como ler  o inicio da mensagem e o final.

Comment: consegui resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizando ByteLength Parser, quem precisar de uma olhada na documentação.

https://serialport.io/docs/en/api-parser-byte-length

segue exemplo, código esta bagunçado sou novo nisso, então estou trabalhando nisso ainda, mas acredito que ajude.

```js
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const Ready = require('@serialport/parser-ready')

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const express = require('express');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo.listen(server);

const port = new SerialPort('COM3', {
 baudRate: 115200,
    dataBits: 8,
    paridade: 'nenhum' ,
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false ,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline('\r')  
});

//define um limite para acionar um evento
const ByteLength = require('@serialport/parser-byte-length');
const parser = port.pipe(new ByteLength({length: 4}))

server.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('Servidor Online na porta 3000');
});


//define um diretorio commo public para acesso as propriedades
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
 maxAge: '1d'
 }));

// retorna index quano recebe requição
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
  maxAge: '1d'
  }));
});
 
 port.open(function()
 {
  console.log('Porta aberta');
 });
 var ModbusTCP = "";
 parser.on('data', function (data)
 {  
   ModbusTCP = data.toString();
   ModbusTCP = ModbusTCP.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); 
   var infLeng = ModbusTCP.length;  
   
   console.log('tamanho do envio:',infLeng);
   console.log('Valor Hexadeciaml: ' + ModbusTCP);
   
   // cria conexao de dados entre o js e o index.html
   io.emit('arduino:data', {
    value: data.toString()
   });
 });
```